# How to revoke user access to database metadata tables in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I am trying to revoke access to a user (be it a testUser or db2instance user) from getting the metadata information of a database using the Sysibm schema. If I run the following query

```
SELECT NAME, COLTYPE, LENGTH FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBNAME = 'tableName';
```

I get the information on the table I had passed in the query. What can be done to restrict this access to a user?

I ran the

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS FROM user;
```

and received the following error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: An attempt to revoke a privilege, security label, exemption, or role from "USER" was denied because "USER" does not hold this privilege, security label, exemption, or role.. SQLCODE=-556, SQLSTATE=42504
```

Even with db2instance user, I get the same error message. However, the select statement gives me the correct result though.

I believe the Sysibm is where all the database related information is stored. I want to restrict access to that so that the user cannot get the metadata about my database.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by hiding catalog information from users? Security by obscurity is hardly beneficial.

Comment: I am validating the ability of my application in handling such a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0054269.html

> In a non-restrictive database, the special group PUBLIC is granted the following privileges:
>
> SELECT on all SYSCAT and SYSIBM tables

(among other things. See the manual page for the full list)

So you need to REVOKE access from `PUBLIC`

You might want to read the article that is linked from the above page too. [A practical guide to restrictive databases](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en-gb#!/wiki/Wc9a068d7f6a6_4434_aece_0d297ea80ab1/page/A%20practical%20guide%20to%20restrictive%20databases)

Comment: The OP should be aware that revoking catalog SELECT privileges may affect the ability of database drivers (both ODBC and JDBC), GUI clients, and many ORM framework to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 10.5.5 you are able to [CREATE PERMISSION](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0057429.html) on system catalog tables. This gives you an ability to "hide" some objects for particular users, but you need to code the logic yourself.

It may be, for example, something like this: a user can see the table definition if it has any table privilege or has `DATAACCESS` or `ACCESSCTRL` on the database...